# Undefined is not a function: while creating a form Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Here is linker.js

```
deps = ['jquery'];
define (deps, function($) {
          var linker = {
               'link' : function(ortholog,link) {
               $form = $.createElement("form");                   
               $form.setAttribute("method", "POST");                   
               $form.setAtrribute("action", link);
               $form.setAttribute("onsubmit" ,window.open(action+ortholog));
               $('body').append($form);
               $form.setAttribute("target","_blank");
               $form[0].submit();
               }
              //return linker();
          }
          return linker;
   });
```

I get a undefined is not a function error after "form = $.createElement("form");"
How can I solve this?
(This linker.js is invoked by another javascript in my software.)

Comment: The dollar sign is most commonly associated with jQuery in javascript and variables starting with the dollar sign usually signify jQuery objects. It would be strange to see `var $form = document.createElement('form')`, but more common to see `var $form = $('<form>')`, which would be how you make a form element in jQuery. Starting variable names with the dollar sign which are just plain javascript values might be misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not...

```
deps = ['jquery'];
define (deps, function($) {
    var linker = {
        'link' : function(ortholog,link) {
            $form = $('<form>');
            $form.attr({
                method: 'POST',
                action: link,
                target: '_blank'
            }).appendTo('body');

            $form.submit(function() {
                window.open(action+ortholog);
            });

            $form.submit();
        }
        //return linker();
    }
    return linker;
});
```

Comment: Does $form.attr's action do something to the actual link that is passed to it? link is a URL(completely different from my current URL) that I have passed to the function, but it turns into an object inside the form.attr?

Answer (score -1):

jQuery has no `$.createElement` function but the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) does:

```
$form = document.createElement("form");
```

Also, your `onsubmit` isn't right. The `window.open` will immediately be executed. You need to assign a function to the property like so:

```
$form.onsubmit = function(){
    window.open(action+ortholog)
};
```

Finally, your `submit()` call is using `$form[0]`. This is a problem because `$form` is a DOM element, so you should not use the `[0]` suffix.

```
$form.submit();
```